# xamarin forms HttpClient incomplete Json

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've created a simple server application that sends a json array to the client.
In my xamarin app I get this every 500 milliseconds. But sometimes (these occurrences are completely random) a single character (ending `]` of the array) is missing from the `json`. So I cannot deserialize `json` string to `object`. I've tested my code in a console application and it is working fine without any problems.

Here is the code for http request:

```
public static async Task<T> Put<T>(string url,object data)
{
    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await client.PutAsync(url,content);

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    string str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Debug.WriteLine(str);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(str);
}

public static async Task<T> Get<T>(string url)
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    Debug.WriteLine(str);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(str);
}
```

And this is the code that sends the actual request:

```
Models.Position pos = await Network.Put<Models.Position>("positions/set", new { longitude = l.Longitude, latitude = l.Latitude });
List<Models.Position> positions = await Network.Get<List<Models.Position>>("positions");
```

Comment: Maybe focus on fixing the server sending the malformed JSON? That's surely the simplest fix.

Comment: @DavidG as I said before the server response is ok. I've tested it in a console application.

Comment: I'd be checking the server side, too. The first thing to look out for would be strings containing newline characters `\x000a` getting expanded to CRLF `\x000d\x000a` on the transport layer which would throw out the Content-Length computed on the server side. The client would be reading Content-Length octets and stopping before your final `]` character.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the server uses laravel and returns this 
return response()->json(Position::where('last_updated','>',Carbon::now()->subMinutes(30))->get(),200);

Comment: To randomly drop a single character from the end of a request is *highly* unusual. HTTP is an extremely robust protocol, and `HttpClient` would almost certainly be giving you very different errors if there were issues on the transmission. So either: 1 - The server is sending bad data and you need to fix that; 2 - Your client code here is doing something wrong (this code is fine and will not give you this problem); or 3 - You are mistaken about dropping the last character, only you can figure this out.

Comment: i think @AlwaysLearning is right, if it only occurs randomly, you should have a look on what you are serializing in that time, and try to work out what's the problem, tho it's just a check, it's possible that it might be the deserialization too, but i would go with the server side first

Comment: So if it's 1 or 3, then you need to diagnose it yourself and if it's 2 then I'm wrong and the code above needs fixing. Either way, I don't think we can help you.

Comment: [{"id":1,"user_id":1,"longitude":37.68,"latitude":56.4,"last_updated":"2019-07-30 10:07:49","created_at":"2019-07-29 15:04:46","updated_at":"2019-07-30 10:07:49"}

[{"id":1,"user_id":1,"longitude":37.68,"latitude":56.4,"last_updated":"2019-07-30 10:08:27","created_at":"2019-07-29 15:04:46","updated_at":"2019-07-30 10:08:27"}]

here are two samples of data. one bad data the other normal data. they are logged by the client app. I think it is neither 1 nor 3. you can see 3 is not right because the last character is missing in the bad data.

Comment: this is not 1 because the data just works fine on a console application.  it is running for an hour or two without a single problem. and the problem is that I think this is not my client's problem but xamarin's HttpClient problem. The only thing that I can think of is request headers. I'll check that out to see if the console app and the android app are the same or their default request headers are different.

Comment: May be it is just your console not writing all the json string to the console because of the length and you might be thinking like you are getting incomplete json !!

Comment: @NirmalSubedi I'm deserializing the json. finally it got solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to DavidG and AlwaysLearning for insisting that the problem is server sided I changed my server from laravel artisan to xampp and the problem is solved. I still cannot understand what was the problem if it was line endings it shouldn't happen at random times.
But it is working now on xampp without any problems.